# Determining the index columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have been experiencing slow queries on a table which has a fairly large number of records.

To reduce performance issues I've created a staging table which contains a subset of the records of that large table to assist in joining with other tables. While this has considerably improved performance, the process of querying the large table to find out which records need to be inserted in the staging table is still quite costly.

[Consulting this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135978.aspx#S4), I used the "costly missing indexes" query to see what indexes could be applied on the large table, however, it suggests that I include almost every column to a single index. Which brings me to my question: Are indexes supposed to be the most commonly fetched columns, or the columns that are most used in search conditions?

Comment: Depends,if you select the whole table or almost, those indexes used in search conditions wont help much.So now sql server suggests the kitchen sink,put everything in an index.

Comment: I need to select all columns in a row, but I only use two columns in search conditions. But if I put all columns in an index, it won't make any difference in performance won't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are used to improve the speed at which the database can find records matching the search criteria, so to answer your question indexes are only useful on columns that are used in search conditions.

Adding indexes to columns that are frequently fetched but never appear as search conditions will serve no purpose other than adding additional overhead to DML operations as the indexes will also have to be maintained.